# Compiling Android application with support library using Ant

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, compilation

How I can compile Android application project that uses Android Support library (with resources) using Ant ?

I have copied android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to libs/ folder inside my application. Code is OK, I have been checked it and compared to code from videotutorial.

App compiles, but I get error while launching, referencing that support library is not referenced correctly. All tutorials I have found refer to IDEs, but I don't like IDE's and I want to do this using terminal..

Logcat log:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
D/AndroidRuntime(17652): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(17652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(17652): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at org.narzew.timetable.PlanLekcji.onCreate(PlanLekcji.java:256)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using Eclipse instead of Android Studio?

Comment: I don't use any IDE. I have too slow PC to run Eclipse or Android Studio.

Comment: Have you tried Gradle then use MavenCentral/JCenter to get your dependencies?